# NavigationController inside TabBarController, or vice versa?

Tags: ios

I apologize if this is simple or answered elsewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm building a tabbed app in which some (but not all) tab views need navigation.  Should I:

1) Use a `UITabBarController` root controller in which the navigation subviews are themselves `UINavigationController` instances.

2) Use a `UINavigationController` root controller, containing a `TabBar` instance, and hide the bar navigation when on a tab that doesn't need navigation services.

3) A totally different architecture.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your choices, you want to do #1. The view controllers that are connected to the tabs can be navigation controllers. In a storyboard, you can start with the tabbed application template, and delete the view controller that's given to you by default, drag in a UINavigationController, and reconnect it to the tabBarController with a relationship segue.

Comment: I did some more research and it sounds like your advice is right.  Thanks!